# PHP from quotation mark output

Tags: php, forms, email, ascii

I use a similar form on a regular basis and have just become aware that whenever a single OR double quotation mark is inputted into the form the output to myself (through email) displays the quotation mark as the ASCII code so \' with a backslash ive looked around and dipped into unique character encodings specialentities but cant seem to find anything that will help output it as a normal quotation mark.

Comment: Can you paste in here your code? I think it might be helpful in solving issues a bit faster.

Comment: Did you check the setting of magic quotes on your system? http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an old security feature from PHP called "Magic Quotes". All Quotes from GET- and POST varables are escaped with the backslash.

You can disable it by changing the value of `magic_quotes_gpc` to `off` in your servers php.ini or manually sanitize the strings using `stripslashes($string)`.

Comment: Hey there thank you i used stripslashes($_POST['comment']); instead of adding a filter_sanitize_string

Comment: But please keep in mind, that your script now depends on `magic_quotes_gpc` is turned on. This feature is marked DEPRECATED and maybe will be removed in future releases of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

it is `magic_quotes_gpc` long-time deprecated ancient PHP setting.
just turn it off

Comment: ok ive turned this off in php.ini but still having the same issue

Comment: make sure you have edited right php.ini file. and restarted server afterwards

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP are you using?  It sounds like you may have magic quotes enabled, a deprecated "feature" that automatically adds backslashes to quotes in `$_GET` and `$_POST`.  It is considered bad practice nowadays to use it, so you should make sure it's disabled.  See [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) page for how to check if it's enabled and disable it.

In general, if you have a string with escaped quotes, you can use `stripslashes` to get rid of them.

```
$str = "\'hello\'";
echo $str . "\n";
//\'hello\'
echo stripslashes($str) . "\n";
//hello
```